# Change icons directory to a xdg base directory

Tags: icons, xdg, base-dir-spec

How can I change the icons directory from `~/.icons` to `$XDG_DATA_HOME/icons/`?

I set `$XDG_DATA_HOME` to `~/.data/`, but it didn't work (it seems that the icon configuration is not compliant to [XDG Base Directory spacification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)).

Comment: Simply make a symlink.

Comment: I've done that.  But I'm looking for a more elegant solution (such as an setting a environment variable or changing a dotfile)

Comment: It depends on the software what you use, if it handles these environments correctly. `~/.icons` is hardcoded often.